# How to filter names from a table and get the row that we want in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, text, filter

For example, I am having a table with columns of *UserName*, *FirstName*, *LastName*, *DOB*, *Address*..

Examples of *UserName* :
SalesSalesManager_TimSmith_ERC
SalesSalesRepresentative_AlberHellstern_BD
BackOfficeReceptionist_CarolinePatterson_QW
BackOfficeMailClerk_XavierMartin_QW
HumanResourceHRManager_LaurentPereira_EE
HumanResourceHRAssistant_AmyAlberts_ERC
... etc

When I want to filter out the whole table with certain *UserName* I want, I type " [asterisk]Alber[asterisk] " in the textbox and the table will be filtered and only the list (together with its *FirstName*, *DOB*, etc) below will appear:
SalesSalesRepresentative_AlberHellstern_BD
HumanResourceHRAssistant_AmyAlberts_ERC

What can we code to do the filtering?

Comment: Are the contents of the table stored in a database?

Comment: Are you using some kind of entity framework? Do you plan to use SQL for this task (not really recommended)? Is there even a database or this "table" is some kind of object you have? Could you show us the code you have?

Comment: Yes, it is stored in a database (XML file). After reading from the file, the table will be created.

Comment: I am using WPF C# for generating the data in a table. I saved all the elements in the column (eg "FirstName", "LastName", etc) using ObservableCollection<T>, databinding it with my MainWindow.xaml, creating it with syncfusion grid tree format.

Comment: Is there a way for me to write it in Regular Expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using EF then you can use linq & you a list of Users of type User then you can write

```
List<User> filtered = User.where(u => u.UserName.ToLower().Contains(FilterString.ToString())).ToList();
```

Where FilterString is of type string and it holds your filter, in your case "alber".